# Polymer 1.0: <polymer-slide> is not rendering inside <template is="dom-repeat">

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I am trying to bind a slideshow in Polymer-ish way with the following code.

**Custom Element HTML**

```html
<template>
  <div id="image_container">
    <!-- Reference URL: https://github.com/Iverum/polymer-slideshow -->
    <polymer-slideshow height="200">
      <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{imageGallery}}">
        <polymer-slide>
          <iron-image style="width:100%; height:200px;" sizing="cover" src="{{_getImage(item.path, item.name)}}"></iron-image>
        </polymer-slide>    
      </template>
    </polymer-slideshow>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
(function () {
    'use strict';

    Polymer({
    is: 'advert-billboard',

    properties: {
      imageGallery: {
        type: Array,
        value: [],
        notify: true
      }
    },

    _getImage: function (path, name) {
      return "/" + path + "/" + name;
    }
  });
})();
</script>
```

I am passing the following JSON from my `index.html` page:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
window.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function (e) {
  var advertBillboard = document.querySelector("advert-billboard");
  if (advertBillboard != null) {
    advertBillboard.imageGallery = [
      { 'name': '1.jpg', 'path': 'images/bb' },
      { 'name': '2.jpg', 'path': 'images/bb' },
      { 'name': '3.jpg', 'path': 'images/bb' },
      { 'name': '4.jpg', 'path': 'images/bb' }
    ];
  }
}
</script>
```

**Following works (when I take out `polymer-slideshow` and `polymer-slide` from within the loop)**:

```html
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{imageGallery}}">
  <iron-image style="width:100%; height:200px;" sizing="cover" src="{{_getImage(item.path, item.name)}}"></iron-image>
</template>
```

**But this doesn't**

```html
<polymer-slideshow height="200">
  <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{imageGallery}}">
    <polymer-slide>
      <iron-image style="width:100%; height:200px;" sizing="cover" src="{{_getImage(item.path, item.name)}}"></iron-image>
    </polymer-slide>    
  </template>
</polymer-slideshow>
```

I am using reference of https://github.com/Iverum/polymer-slideshow

**UPDATE** When I put my slideshow images statically, they get rendered and slideshow moves!

```html
<polymer-slideshow height="200">
  <polymer-slide>
    <iron-image style="width:100%; height:200px;" sizing="cover" src="1.jpg"></iron-image>
  </polymer-slide>
  <polymer-slide>
    <iron-image style="width:100%; height:200px;" sizing="cover" src="2.jpg"></iron-image>
  </polymer-slide>
  <polymer-slide>
    <iron-image style="width:100%; height:200px;" sizing="cover" src="3.jpg"></iron-image>
  </polymer-slide>
</polymer-slideshow>
```

Seeing that I took out the computed method from the loop and put an image statically in `image src`, which is supposed to load the same image but at least I was trying to see whether they render! No luck :( This is what I tried:

```html
<polymer-slideshow height="200">
  <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{imageGallery}}">
    <polymer-slide>
      <iron-image style="width:100%; height:200px;" sizing="cover" src="1.jpg"></iron-image>
    </polymer-slide>    
  </template>
</polymer-slideshow>
```

Comment: I think it could be a problem with the implementation of `polymer-slideshow`. I quick look at the source code revealed that the `polymer-slidehow` will only select content children of type `polymer-slide`. I guess it is ignoring the `dom-repeat`. To confirm this, you could try omitting the `polymer-slidehow` element. However, you will then not have a working slideshow.

Comment: You could also try to modify line 80 in polymer-slideshow.html and remove the `select`. Basically just leaving an empty `<content></content>` element.

Comment: `<content></content>` is not working either. It looks like I might go for a slideshow plugin. To add, there is a component `polymer-ui-carousel` but when I tried to install it using `bower install polymer-ui-carousel` it said `Repository not found`. Is this not available any more?

Answer (score 0):

Do recheck the source.

```
<iron-image style="width:100%; height:200px;" sizing="cover" src="1.jpg"></iron-image>
```

The computed  function return `/images/bb/1.jpg`. Try displaying the src address. If the src address is displayed properly like you intent, then you can rule out this possibility.

Comment: Do you mean http://locahost:3000 to be prefixed with "/images/bb/1.jpg"? If yes, I wonder how the images are rendering when I am putting multiple `<polymer-slide>` nodes statically without any looping?

Comment: No, I was merely referring to the src you entered in <polymer-slide> nodes statically without any looping.